# DataWeave Transform Message transforms 8192 bytes when deployed to Cloudhub

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am receiving a JSON request with 3 attribute and one of the attribute is content of image which is base64 in string format. After receiving this request I am creating a Salesforce attachment using Salesforce connector.

Now when I test this via my local Anypoint Studio everything is fine, however after deploying to Cloudhub the fileContent (Image content) is getting truncated to 8192 bytes and creating the attachment as corrupted.

I can see API is receiving the content since message content length is 38820 (both local and Cloudhub), and it looks like message is getting lost after the Message Transformation, and code is as follows:

```
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
             <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                 <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/java
 ---
 {
     accountId : payload.accountId,
     name : 'MyProfilePicture',
     ContentType: payload.contentType,
     fileContent : payload.fileContent
 }]]></dw:set-payload>
             </dw:transform-message>

             <set-session-variable variableName="accountId" value="#[payload.accountId]" doc:name="Session Variable - accountId"/>
             <set-session-variable variableName="contentType" value="#[payload.ContentType]" doc:name="Session Variable - contentType"/>
             <logger message="payload.fileContent Before Conversion size #[payload.fileContent.length()], data:#[payload.fileContent] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
             <set-session-variable variableName="fileContent" value="#[(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(payload.fileContent))]" mimeType="binary/octet-stream" doc:name="Session Variable - fileContent"/>
             <dw:transform-message metadata:id="1676949a-75ba-4e51-82ac-b5788a8e87dc" doc:name="Transform Message">
                 <dw:input-payload/>
                 <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/java
 ---
 [{
     Name: 'MyProfilePicture',
     ParentId: sessionVars.accountId,
     ContentType: sessionVars.contentType,
     Body: sessionVars.fileContent
 }]]]></dw:set-payload>
             </dw:transform-message>
             <logger message="Payload after Transform Message: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
             <sfdc:create config-ref="Salesforce__Cfg" type="Attachment" doc:name="Salesforce">
                 <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
             </sfdc:create>
         </processor-chain>
```

Could anyone please help on this? why when I deploy to Cloudhub it is only processing 8192 bytes?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by switching to the deprecated DataMapper for the huge base64 transforms.